# veth does not respond to other veth ping requests on same bridge

Tags: linux-networking, ping, bridge, ubuntu-20.04

I created two veth pairs and connected them to the same bridge. However, they do not respond to ping requests. This is ubuntu 20.04.

```sh
# create the interfaces and bridge  
sudo ip link add br0 type bridge
sudo ip link add i0 type veth peer name i0-p
sudo ip link add i1 type veth peer name i1-p

# connect veth peers into bridge as well as physical interface 
sudo ip link set eno2 master br0
sudo ip link set i0-p master br0
sudo ip link set i1-p master br0

# bring up all the interfaces/bridges up. 
sudo ip link set br0 up
sudo ip link set eno2 up
sudo ip link set i0-p up 
sudo ip link set i1-p up 
sudo ip link set i0 up 
sudo ip link set i1 up 

# set the addresses 
sudo ip a add 10.0.10.4/16 dev br0
sudo ip a add 10.0.10.5/16 dev i0
sudo ip a add 10.0.10.6/16 dev i1
```

```sh
                                                                                   
                                                                                   
                                             +-------------+                       
                                             |             |                       
         +---------+               +---------|             |                       
         |         |               |         |             |                       
         |  i0     |---------------|  i0-p   |             |                       
         |         |               |         |             |                       
         |10.0.10.5/16             |         |             |            +---------+
         |         |               |         |             |            |         |
         +---------+               +---------|             |            |  en02   |
                                             |     br0     |------------|         |
                                             |             |            |         |
                                             |10.0.10.4/16 |            |         |
         +---------+               +---------+             |            +---------+
         |         |               |         |             |                       
         |  i1     |---------------|  i1-p   |             |                       
         |         |               |         |             |                       
         |10.0.10.6/16             |         |             |                       
         |         |               |         |             |                       
         +---------+               +---------+             |                       
                                             |             |                       
                                             +-------------+
```

```sh
# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a4:bf:01:55:f3:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.20.3/16 brd 192.168.255.255 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a6bf:1ff:fe55:f3a4/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a4:bf:01:55:f3:a5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::a6bf:1ff:fe55:f3a5/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:09:12:3c:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:b1:3c:cd:ab:b0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.10.4/16 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::30b1:3cff:fecd:abb0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
11: i0-p@i0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 32:b1:3c:cd:ab:b0 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::30b1:3cff:fecd:abb0/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
12: i0@i0-p: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ba:04:42:b1:62:f8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.10.5/16 scope global i0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b804:42ff:feb1:62f8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: i1-p@i1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 72:b0:ab:ca:c4:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::70b0:abff:feca:c455/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: i1@i1-p: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f6:47:29:14:84:bb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.10.6/16 scope global i1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f447:29ff:fe14:84bb/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

```sh
# sysctl -p
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

```sh
# ping 10.0.10.6 -I i0
PING 10.0.10.6 (10.0.10.6) from 10.0.10.5 i0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.0.10.6 ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 13296ms
```

```sh
# tcpdump -i i0 not stp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on i0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
06:25:12.616946 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:13.625187 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:14.649177 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:15.673372 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:16.697226 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:17.721230 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:18.745363 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:19.769271 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:20.793229 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:21.817332 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:22.841256 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:23.865261 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:24.889354 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:25.913245 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
06:25:26.937169 ARP, Request who-has kolla01 tell kolla01, length 28
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

**UPDATE:**
applying suggestions made by kab00m:

```sh
# tcpdump -ni lo
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
15:59:00.976656 IP 10.0.10.2 > 10.0.10.2: ICMP host 10.0.10.3 unreachable, length 92
15:59:00.976667 IP 10.0.10.2 > 10.0.10.2: ICMP host 10.0.10.3 unreachable, length 92
15:59:00.976674 IP 10.0.10.2 > 10.0.10.2: ICMP host 10.0.10.3 unreachable, length 92
15:59:04.080688 IP 10.0.10.2 > 10.0.10.2: ICMP host 10.0.10.3 unreachable, length 92
15:59:04.080698 IP 10.0.10.2 > 10.0.10.2: ICMP host 10.0.10.3 unreachable, length 92
15:59:04.080705 IP 10.0.10.2 > 10.0.10.2: ICMP host 10.0.10.3 unreachable, length 92
15:59:07.152677 IP 10.0.10.2 > 10.0.10.2: ICMP host 10.0.10.3 unreachable, length 92
^C
7 packets captured
14 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

```sh
# destroy everything 
sudo ip link delete i0
sudo ip link delete i1
sudo ip link delete br0 

# create namespaces 
ip netns add net0 
ip netns add net1 

# create veth pairs and bridge 
ip link add i0 type veth peer name i0-p
ip link add i1 type veth peer name i1-p
ip link add br0 type bridge

# add devices to network namespace 
ip link set i0 netns net0
ip link set i1 netns net1

# add second peers into bridge 
ip link set eno2 master br0
ip link set i0-p master br0
ip link set i1-p master br0

# add addresses 
ip a add 10.0.10.4/16 dev br0
ip netns exec net0 ip a add 10.0.10.5/16 dev i0 
ip netns exec net1 ip a add 10.0.10.6/16 dev i1

# bring up all devices 
ip netns exec net0 ip link set i0 up
ip netns exec net1 ip link set i1 up
ip link set i0-p up
ip link set i1-p up
ip link set br0 up
ip link set eno2 up
```

```sh
# ip netns exec net0 ping 10.0.10.6 -I i0
PING 10.0.10.6 (10.0.10.6) from 10.0.10.5 i0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.10.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.10.6: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.10.6: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
^C
--- 10.0.10.6 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2046ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.051/0.053/0.058/0.003 ms
```

Comment: Is it what you have searched for? Please, mark answer helpful if it is.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you try to achieve.

Main problem of this setup is that reply packet won't be sent over veth interface, because IP is assigned to the same host. When ARP reply packet tries to go out it should detect outgoing interface based on routing table. And routing tells that this address is assigned to same host therefore reply will come via lo interface. You can listen to `tcpdump -ni lo` to see replies and likely you would find unreacheables there.

You can either create virtual machines like LXC/docker or use other network namespaces. man veth(4) to know more about latter.

btw, net.ipv4.ip_forward have nothing with ethernet packets or bridging, this way you can tell the kernel to forward packet if kernel got it by itself, like for routing.

Comment: might help nat that all might also a overkill but it could work

Comment: NAT does nothing with layer 2 bridging.